# Sort object by values using Underscore in Node.js

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

If I have an object like this how can I sort using the underscore module in node.js so the values are highest to lowest so that...

```
 { ZZX: 1, FRA: 5, GBR: 2, USA: 3 }
```

..becomes

```
{ FRA: 5, USA: 3, GBR: 2, ZZX: 1 }
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: [There's no guaranteed key order for JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) so you probably need an array to accommodate this.

Comment: A posible fix : `var obj = { FRA: 5, USA: 3, GBR: 2, ZZX: 1 };
var keys = 
           Object.keys(obj).map(e=>({
               country: e, 
                score : obj[e]
})).sort((a, b)=>b.score - a.score);

keys.map(JSON.stringify).forEach(alert);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
sortedKeys = _.sortBy(Object.keys(obj), function(key){ return obj[key]; }).reverse();
newHash = {};
sortedKeys.forEach (e => (newHash[e] = obj[e]));
console.log(newHash)
```